# How can I save request parameters along with exception Flask?

Tags: python, error-handling, flask

When a Flask application throws an an exception, we generally have an error handler that will catch it:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def serverError(e):
    # log to file or something
    app.logger.error(e)
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

How can we also log some extra data like the request parameters? A lot of times, it's useful to know what the input was that caused the exception in addition to the exception message itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just log whatever data you want from the `request`, it's still available in the error handler.  Here's a simple handler that logs the headers and any data sent with the request.  Note that the exception is already logged by Flask, you don't need to log it separately.

```
# make sure to add your own handler when not in debug mode
if not app.debug:
    app.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

@app.errorhandler(500)
def teardown_request(e):
    app.logger.error(request.headers)

    if request.args:
        app.logger.error(request.args)

    if request.form:
        app.logger.error(request.form)
    elif request.get_json():
        app.logger.error(request.get_json())

    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```